# multiple files as argument in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that exports log files, usually I get between 1-3 separate files depending on the size of the log for a particular day. After the export I run a report generator to spit out an html document of those logs. My question is how to call the command that generates the reports depending on the number of files, I know I can use if statements and do:

```
./generateReport -i file1 -o output.html

./generateReport -i file1 file2 -o output.html

./generateReport -i file1 file2 file3 -o output.html
```

is there a way to loop over the files and include them as an input??

Comment: It would be more conventional to use `-i file1 -i file2 -o output.html`, or to remove `-i` altogether (`file1 file2 -o output.html`)

Comment: Use positional parameters rather than flags for multiple input files.

Comment: Was the question how to **implement** `generateReport` (to parse names off the command line when called through the given convention), or how to **call** `generateReport`? I read it as the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filename expansion :

```
./generateReport -i file? -o output.html
```

or using `find` for all log files created in the last 24 hours :

```
./generateReport -i `find . -name "file*" -mtime -1` -o output.html
```

Comment: The second one is buggy, if any of your filenames contain spaces in them. See also [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), which applies.

Answer (score 3):

Is it necessary to use flags?

```
./generateReport file1 file2 file3 > output.html
```

Comment: Yes it is, since I am using a tool to generate logs and it uses -i to start reading input files to it

Answer (score 2):

The following will collect an array of inputFiles, and a single variable with the output file name:

```
inputFiles=( )
outputFile=
while (( $# )); do
  if [[ $1 = -o ]]; then
    outputFile=$2; shift
  elif [[ $1 = -i ]]; then
    inputFiles+=( "$2" ); shift
  else
    inputFiles+=( "$1" )
  fi
  shift
done
```

...then, you could do something like this:

```
# redirect stdout to the output file, if one was given
[[ $outputFile ]] && exec >"$outputFile"

# loop over the input files and process each one
for inputFile in "${inputFiles[@]}"; do
  process "$inputFile"
done
```